# SQL query which get MIN of a column and multiply it with other column's value

Tags: sql, database

I try to make a sql query which returns the ID of customers, their account's currencies and the end of year amounts of their accounts by multiplying the current amount with **the minimum interest rates of all acount**

Tables are like

```
**customer**       **account**
 id                  id
 name                customer_id
 surname             curreny
                     cur_Amount
                     interest_rate
```

I made a query like below but it only returns the one row which has the minimum interest rate.

`SELECT customer.id, account.currency, account.cur_amount, MIN(account.interest_rate)*cur_amount AS End_Year_Balance
FROM customer, account LEFT JOIN account on customer.id = account.customer_id`

How can I list all the accounts with the cutsomer ID's and end year balance by mutliplying the minimum of the interest rate ?

Thank you

Comment: DBMS? SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres?

Comment: not important actually:)  But MySQL would be better so I can test it

Answer (score 0):

This will work on MySQL

```
SELECT min(interest_rate) into @min_interest from account;

SELECT customer.id,account.currency,account.cur_amount,@min_interest*cur_amount AS End_Year_Balance 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN account 
ON customer.id = account.customer_id;
```

This will work on any DB:

```
SELECT customer.id,account.currency,account.cur_amount,temp.min_interest*cur_amount AS End_Year_Balance 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN account ON customer.id = account.customer_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT min(interest_rate) as min_interest from account) temp ON 1=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    customer.id, customer.name, customer.surname,
    account.id, account.currency, account.cur_Amount, account.interest_rate,
    account.cur_Amount * A2.LowestInterestRate

FROM
    customer
    INNER JOIN account ON (customer.id = account.customer_id)
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT customer.id, MIN(interest_rate) LowestInterestRate 
         FROM account 
         GROUP BY customer.id
    ) AS A2 ON (customer.id = A2.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **ambiguity** from query and should use `GROUP BY` if you use **AGGREGATE** functions. However, this is an sample query which works on similar situation.

```
select a.custid, a.custname, a.surname, 
b.accid, b.currency, b.curamount, b.interestrate, b.EndYearBalance 
from customer a 
left outer join 
(
select accid, custid, currency, curamount, MIN(interestrate) AS interestrate, 
ISNULL(MIN(interestrate)*curamount, 0) AS EndYearBalance 
from  account 
group by accid, custid, currency, curamount   
) as b on a.custid = b.custid
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    a.currency,
    a.cur_amount,
    a.cur_amount * (SELECT MIN(interest_rate) FROM account)
FROM
    customer c left join account a on c.id = a.customer_id
```

Comment: When he said "all accounts", I think he meant "all accounts *for the current customer*". So the subquery should probably match on `customer_id` too.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but after re-reading his post and some of the replies, I think there is a 1:1 relationship between customer and account and he really means the lowest interest rate of all accounts.  But I agree it's ambiguous, so we'll just have to wait for the OP to clarify.  brsbilgic?